# Image indexer and duplicate finder

Tags: gratis, images, file-management

I need a free program, that is able to index my images on my hard disk and find duplicates.

I'd like to be able to find exact duplicates (same size, name and format could be different) as well as slightly modified (cropped) and resized.

Ordering files by date (of taking a shot, from EXIF data) would be a nice feature.

Must run on Windows.

Comment: I feel like Infranview can do this, but I'm not sure.
A Bash script using using ImageMagic could almost definately do it. (though i'm not sure exactly how)

Comment: See also [Free visual similarity image for a local hard drive search?](http://superuser.com/questions/311633/free-visual-similarity-image-for-a-local-hard-drive-search), [How can I find duplicate photos?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/4072/how-can-i-find-duplicate-photos), [How can I find duplicate photos in about 100gb of data?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/26026/how-can-i-find-duplicate-photos-in-about-100gb-of-data)

Comment: Is this one-shot or incremental? That is, are you going to run the program from time to time, or do you want images to be quickly added to the index and flagged if they are duplicates without having to scan the whole collection each time?

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [VisiPics](http://www.visipics.info/index.php?title=Main_Page):

> It will detect two different resolution files of the same
>   picture as a duplicate, or the same picture saved in different
>   formats, or duplicates where only minor cosmetic changes have taken
>   place.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I read on the your link "Note: After 338,950 downloads, more than 2,000 per week ; the link to Download.com has been removed. Click here for more information..." I didn't find out if download without a wrapping accompanying  bloat-ware is still possible.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. What are your personal experiences with this tools? Did you use them? Do they have any problems or features you find particularly awesome? Please do elaborate a bit more on this.

Comment: Please [read our discussion on what makes an answer high quality](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/356/185) to see if you can incorporate some of these improvements into your answer.

Comment: VisiPics is a great tool. I've used it many times to remove duplicate images. You want to start out with a Filter of strict to detect exact visual matches, but may want to be more fuzzy if you get no results. The less strict search will find images that are close but not exact. Be careful with this setting. Auto Select is very useful in that it will select the inferior image (lower resolution for example) to be deleted. Even on a SSD, it can take a few hours to process 100GB of photos (file count 23,000) as the comparison is very CPU intensive.

Answer (score 0):

[dupeGuru PE](http://www.hardcoded.net/dupeguru_pe/). Plus it's open-source. :)

> dupeGuru Picture Edition (PE for short) is a tool to find duplicate
>   pictures on your computer. dupeGuru PE is a big brother of dupeGuru.
>   It works like dupeGuru, but is specialized for duplicate pictures
>   matching. dupeGuru PE runs on Windows, Mac OS X and Linux.
>
> dupeGuru PE is efficient. Not only can dupeGuru PE find exact matches,
>   but it can also find duplicates among pictures of different kind (PNG,
>   JPG, GIF etc..) and quality. On Mac OS X, dupeGuru PE can scan your
>   iPhoto library.
>
> dupeGuru PE is customizable. You can tweak its matching engine to find
>   exactly the kind of duplicates you want to find. The Preference page
>   of the help file lists all the scanning engine settings you can
>   change.
>
> dupeGuru PE is safe. Its engine has been especially designed with
>   safety in mind. Its reference directory system as well as its grouping
>   system prevent you from deleting pictures you didn't mean to delete.
>
> Compare any picture format. dupeGuru PE supports JPG, PNG, TIFF, GIF
>   and BMP formats. All these formats can be compared together. The Mac
>   OS X version of dupeGuru PE also supports PSD and RAW (CR2 and NEF)
>   formats.
>
> Your iPhoto and Aperture libraries are supported.
>
> Do whatever you want with your duplicates. Not only can you delete
>   duplicates files dupeGuru finds, but you can also move or copy them
>   elsewhere. There are also multiple ways to filter and sort your
>   results to easily weed out false duplicates (for low threshold scans).

(answer is copied from https://superuser.com/questions/311633/free-visual-similarity-image-for-a-local-hard-drive-search/453251#453251 - all credit to [enter link description here](http://chrome://leechblock/content/delayed.xhtml?4&https://superuser.com/users/43406/pat))