# Software to find duplicated pictures using visual representation for Windows

Tags: windows, images, file-management

I want an application/software that is able to find duplicated pictures and organize them one next to each other in a group.

I would like an app that actually has visual representation of the pictures as I haven't named them in a specific way, so just by showing me the names of the files it would be the same as if I just decide to organize my pictures manually.

I have a lot of pictures and quite some of them got duplicated, by being backed up and transferred from one device to another too many times. The problem is that the duplicated copies are with all different names and sizes, just the content is the same. So I was wondering does anyone knows a free desktop application/software (for Windows) that can search a folder and organize the same by content pictures in groups so I'm actually able to see how many copies of each pic do I have and keep only the best quality one and delete the rest. I don't want the application to delete the duplicated ones automatically as some of my pictures are very similar, but not exactly the same and I'm afraid that if it deletes them automatically it may not recognize those as different and I will end up not losing some of them.

In summary, I need to compare the images themself, not the file names/size.

Comment: Please check with the following questions: [Software to find duplicate files](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/948/185) / **[Image indexer and duplicate finder](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/290/185)**

Comment: Thank you Izzy, I actually looked at this before I post my question, but I would like better an App that actually has visual representation of the pictures as I haven't named them in a specific way, so just by showing me the names of the files it would be the same as if I just decide to organize my pictures manually.

Comment: Good points, Ramzy. Maybe you'd like to [edit] your question and integrate that directly? Always a good idea to show you've looked into other questions and point out why they don't fit. Not only it shows your research effort, but it also saves you from being suggested things you've already checked with :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [VisiPics](http://www.visipics.info)
- [Similar Image Search](http://sourceforge.net/projects/similarimagesearch/)
- [Image Search Pony](http://download.cnet.com/windows/visual-search-pony/3260-2193_4-10091863-1.html)
- [Anti-Twin](http://www.joerg-rosenthal.com/en/antitwin/)

All do pretty much the same. They search for the same images and list them for you, then you can choose to send them to the recycle bin or delete them immediately. The listed software is free to use.

Comment: The they sound awesome. Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much Zerotime!