# Recommended software to remove duplicated photos

Tags: windows, file-management, photography

Based on https://www.pcworld.com/article/2927913/find-duplicate-photos-two-utilities-that-can-help.html, I installed http://freepicturesolutions.com/free-duplicate-photo-finder.html on Windows 10, however, it doesn't appear to be Windows 10 compatible and the application will not open.

So, then I install https://www.duplicatephotosfixer.com/, and after an hour of scanning my system, get the following popup.  The website didn't list this 15 photo limitation.  Well, I can spend the next year and a half doing it...
[image]

[Software to find duplicated pictures using visual representation for Windows](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/18446/software-to-find-duplicated-pictures-using-visual-representation-for-windows) gives 4 options, but doesn't provide any recommendations.

- https://sourceforge.net/projects/similarimagesearch/ has a user rating of 1.
- http://download.cnet.com/windows/visual-search-pony/3260-2193_4-10091863-1.html has a user rating of 2.
- http://www.joerg-rosenthal.com/en/antitwin/download.html hasn't been updated since 2010, and doesn't list Windows 10.

That leaves http://www.visipics.info/index.php?title=Main_Page.  Any good?

What about others?